# CentOS 6 - Kernel 3 from CentOS 7 Repo?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

i want to run kernel 3 on centos 6. I found out, that it cant get installed over yum and i would need to compile it by my own.

My question: Could i use the centos 7 repo to install kernel 3.x from there? I cant find out the correct repo file for centos7, i would need to hardcode the variables but i dont know the value:

> mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os

Would i can install Kernel 3 from CentOS 7 repo?

Comment: I'm pretty sure people have 3.x kernel already compiled for your version&architecture. You may wan to try OVH's 3.10 ftp://ftp.ovh.net/made-in-ovh/bzImage/
   I wouldn't want to use CentOS 7's because of systemd(but i may be confusing everything)

Comment: I would recommend not installing a CentOS 7 package on a CentOS 6 system. Going the other way is more acceptable, but I still wouldn't want to do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly not recommended because it changes a basic building block of the distribution and will certainly create unpredictable behavior in your system. If you want to do it for fun, compile the kernel from scratch (there are many tutorials showing how to do that).

My suggestion is to use CentOS 7 which offers kernel 3.x thoroughly tested with all the other components. You can take advantage of the fact that CentOS 6->7 is the first supported [upgrade](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/chap-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Migration_Planning_Guide-Upgrade_Tools.html) path.

Answer (score 1):

To get a recent long-term support kernel purpose-built for CentOS 6, consider using [kernel-lt](http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-lt) from [ELrepo](http://elrepo.org/).